# Search text "\**" throws error "Failed to parse query string." but "\*", "\*~" and "\~~" works

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

If the user starts a search, we automatically create a start with expression e.g. user input: "Hello" => azure search input "Hello*".

If the user types in a special characters like "+", "-", "!", "*", "~", etc. (Full list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt589323.aspx#bkmk_syntax) we automatically escape it with a "\" e.g. user input: He**o => azure search input: He\*\*o*

This works good, but if the user input is "*" (=> "\**") azure search throws an error "Failed to parse query string.". This do not happen for "\*", "\*~" and "\~~".

How can I avoid that and is "\**" the only exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcard operator '*' you are appending to query terms enables prefix search query. The prefix search query '\**' is returning 400 because Azure Search disallows '*' to be used as the first character in a prefix search query regardless whether it is escaped or not. The character '*' is the only character that a prefix search query cannot begin with. Thank you very much for reporting this. The error message isn't clear in this case and we will improve it.

By the way, was it your intention to find documents that contain terms that start with '*' in issuing the search query "\**"?

Nate

Comment: Thanks! 'By the way, was it your intention to find documents that contain terms that start with '*' in issuing the search query "\**"? ' Nothing, it's just a input that has been entered by the user. As a workaround we filter these out to prevent errors.